# django filtering a model that contains integer

Tags: python, django, django-models, filtering, django-queryset

models.py

```
STORY_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Computer engineering'),
    (1, 'Mechanical engineering')
    )
```

views.py

```
story_list = MyOBJ.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get('q')
if query:
       story_list = story_list.filter(
           Q(story__icontains=query)
       ).distinct()
```

story takes data from STORY_CHOICES, when I try to search and write 'Computer engineering' it gives nothing.
Also '0' is giving 'Computer engineering'. 
I want to cover it to text and take it string search.
I try to take directly STORY_CHOICES and I met this fail:
FieldError at /...
Cannot resolve keyword 'STORY_CHOICES' into field. Choices are: ....
I didn't find a true way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
in_filter = []
query = request.GET.get('q', '').lower()
for k, v in MyOBJ().STORY_CHOICES:
    if query in v.lower():
        in_filter.append(k)
if query:
    story_list = story_list.filter(
        Q(story__in=in_filter)
    ).distinct()
```